# AIX question on cp command

Tags: shell-script, cp

I have come across an issue with the cp command.

We are using ksh; the `cp` command goes like below

```
cp -p $PATH/file_name_${VARIABLE}_???.dat $PATH/file_name_to.dat
```

`???` - is for any three digit numbers. This has been running in a job for long time without any issues. All of a sudden, today this job failed with this error.

```
**cp -p $PATH/file_name_20140911_942.dat $PATH/file_name_20140911_942.dat $PATH/file_name_to.dat
cp: $PATH/file_name_to.dat: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.**
```

`$PATH` was expanded correctly in our job log.

Could someone clarify for me what could have caused the from file to appear twice in cp command which caused it to fail?

Comment: Are you really using the variable name `PATH`? This variable has a standard meaning, so your script wouldn't work. Please post your real code.

Comment: If `cp` displays an error message containing `$PATH`, then it means the script you ran is not what you show, but has the dollar sign quoted. Don't lie to us. Post your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards (e.g., `???`) are expanded
(i.e., replaced by the name(s) of the file(s) that match them)
immediately after you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, before the `cp` program starts running. 
And, naturally, they are expanded (replaced) based on the file(s) that exist
*at that moment*. 
If a file whose name was included in that expansion is deleted (or even renamed)
before `cp` gets around to opening it, the open will fail,
and you will get errors like the ones you have shown.

Comment: I think I'm following - but maybe I don't get why was the *same* filename expanded into `$PATH/file_name_${VARIABLE}_???.dat` twice? Maybe it's just the log format because I also find it strange that the output seems to expand `$VARIABLE` but not `$PATH.` Perhaps the same filename existed in two different directories in `$PATH` at execution time? Can you explain this: *`cp -p $PATH/file_name_20140911_942.dat $PATH/file_name_20140911_942.dat $PATH/file_name_to.dat`*?

Comment: The question says, "$PATH was expanded correctly in our job log." I don't understand why the same filename would appear twice, either.

Comment: $PATH was expanded correctly in log. Instead of mentioning the exact PATH (/usr/data/), i mentioned as $PATH.

Comment: I am not sure why we have copy command expanded input file twice. That's what I am curious to know. when we restarted the job it completed fine. Nothing was changed.